# How to Enable DNN translation through Microsoft Translator API

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator

Microsoft Translate API defaults to performing `Statistical machine translation`. This is lower quality than the more modern `Deep Neural Network` translation, which is also available for many languages.

I am able to get translations to work with `SMT`. However, I'm unable to figure out how to get `DNN` to work. Microsoft's own [documentation](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html) provides no information on this.

Anyone have experience getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translations to and from Chinese and Hindi are NN by default. For the other 18 languages supported, just add the parameter “category=generalnn” to tell our service to use the NN models instead of the SMT ones. More details on language supported and hybrid translations can be found on the Translator blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/translation/2017/11/15/microsoft-translator-accelerates-use-of-neural-networks-across-its-offerings/

Comment: Which endpoints does it work for? It does not work for POST `GetTranslations` endpoint